# Passing more than one parameter to the url

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios, sequelize.js

im trying to pass two parameters to my Url, one for displaying data by type and one for searching by title, year, etc...
my problem is when i try to pass the second parameter it always go as undefined for some reason
this is my url
`router.get("/documents/serach/:key?/:sort?", verifyUser, getAllDocuments);`

this is my axios call

```
 const getDocuments = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:5000/documents/serach/${query}?/${query2}?`
    );
    setDocuments(response.data);
  };
```

i tried using `params: { key: query1, sort: query2 },` as well but it didnt work.
only the first parameter get passed even if i switch them, whatever was written first works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding a pretty fundamental aspect of HTTP. Here is a wikipedia page about query strings that might helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

If you are sure that query string is the best way to send these values to your server you will also want to check out this documentation for Express (assuming that is what you are using).

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query

You will want to do something like this:

```js
const getDocuments = async () => {
    const query = new URLSearchParams({ key: query1, sort: query2 })
    const response = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5000/documents/search/?${query}`
    );
    setDocuments(response.data);
  };
```

Then your route definition would look like this:

```js
router.get('/documents/search', verifyUser, getAllDocuments);

async function getAllDocuments(req, res) {
    const { key, sort } = req.query;

    // ...
}
```

Here is some documentation on `URLSearchParams()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams